# How to Update column values of t1 from Table t2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select t2 column values (Name) and update with t1 column values (Name) without where clause. what will be the query?

I am executing below code:

```
update t1 set t1.name=t2.name from t2 where t1.id=t2.id
```

but I want to perform it without `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to do it as a practice

Comment: let me rephrase, what do  you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join both tables on `id`:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.Name = t2.Name
FROM TableName1 t1
INNER JOIN TableName2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

just do it

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.name=t2.name
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

We use `MERGE` nowadays:

```
MERGE t1 USING t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET name = t2.name;
```